# onmouserover() getting error: assigning to rvalue

Tags: javascript

New to JS so sorry if this is a noob mistake. I googled and couldn't find why this was happening. I'm following the syntax right(according to this website) but I keep getting the error `Assigning to rvalue` on the line `nav_bar.onmouseover() = function() {hide()};`. I tried just calling the `hide` function by itself without the onmouseevent() and that doesn't work either. Am I referencing the html element wrong? Here's my JS code:

```
let nav_bar = document.getElementsByClassName('link_div');

function show()
{
    nav_bar.style.visibility === 'visibile';
}

function hide()
{
    nav_bar.style.visibility === 'hidden';
}

nav_bar.onmouseover() = function() {hide()};
```

And here's my HTML code for the JS link(which I might have done wrong as well):

```
 <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
 </head>
```

Comment: Change `document.getElementsByClassName` to `document.querySelector(".link_div")`. `document.getElementsByClassName` matches ALL elements whereas querySelector matches the first.

Comment: So you reference the element before it exists and you treat an HTML collection like it is a single element. Look at the error message in your console

Comment: @epascarello I'm using cs50's IDE so I don't have an error message other than the one I described.

Comment: You do not run it in the browser?

Comment: @epascarello Ah, didn't know that dev tools had a console. That makes things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
nav_bar.onmouseover() = function() {hide()};
```

you can do

```
nav_bar[0].onmouseover = function() {hide()};
```

also `nav_bar` will be an HTMLCollection

```
let nav_bar = document.getElementsByClassName('link_div');
```

so you can do

```
nav_bar[0]
```

Comment: It's not technically an array, it's an `HTMLCollection`

Comment: Another nitpick: `nav_bar.onmouseover = function() {hide()};` can become `nav_bar.onmouseover = hide;`. Also, it should be `nav_bar[0]`

Comment: Thanks, you cleared up the error but it isn't working as intended. I changed the ```.getElementsByClassName``` to ```querySelector('.link_div')``` to select the div that has that class but it isn't hiding it on mouse hover.

Comment: `querySelector('.link_div')` will return the first matched element or it will return `null`

Comment: @prabeen90 Yes, I only have one element with the class ```link_div``` (which is the one I'm trying to hide). I also changed ```nav_bar.style.visibility = `hidden` ``` since I'm trying to make it hidden. Just realized that it's set to ```null``` for some reason.

Comment: Edit: fixed. for some reason I had the js import file as "text/javascript". Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements. You need to set the visibility of **all** of them. Try this:

```js
let nav_bars = document.getElementsByClassName('link_div');

function show() {
  for (let nav_bar of nav_bars) {
    nav_bar.style.visibility = 'visibile'
  }
}

function hide() {
  for (let nav_bar of nav_bars) {
    nav_bar.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}

for (let nav_bar of nav_bars) {
  nav_bar.onmouseover = hide;
}
```

```html
<div class="link_div">I'm a navbar</div>
```

There are also a number of issues I fixed.

Comment: Thank you! wish I could mark 2 questions as answers :)

Comment: Just mark the one that worked for you. I'll survive going without the reputation!